# Trying to access an Array as part of JSON api in Swift 3.0

Tags: arrays, json, swift3, xcode8

I am trying to access an Array as part of an JSON api. The api does is not part of a dictionary. The function I have is the following:

```
func downloadJsonwithURL() {
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
     URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URL)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSArray {
            print(jsonObj!)

            if let albumsArray = jsonObj! as? NSArray {
                for album in albumsArray{
                    if let albumDict = album as? NSDictionary {
                        if let name = albumDict.value(forKey: "title") {
                            self.nameArray.append(name as! String)
                        }
                        if let name = albumDict.value(forKey: "artist") {
                            self.albumArray.append(name as! String)
                        }
                        if let name = albumDict.value(forKey: "thumbnail_image") {
                            self.imgURLArray.append(name as! String)
                        }
                        if let name = albumDict.value(forKey: "image") {
                            self.albumURLArray.append(name as! String)
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            })
        }

    }).resume()

    }
```

The error I get is

```
 Non-optional expression of type 'NSArray' used in a check for optionals.
```

How can I fix this?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the if-let binding `if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject` you cast `jsonObj` to an NSArray. Therefore, the if-let: `if let albumsArray = jsonObj! as? NSArray { }` is unnecessary. You can delete that line of code (and corresponding closing curly brace) and rename `jsonObj` to `albumsArray`.